# What determines the position of the adverb? Example: I could never learn to swim. or I never could learn to swim

Tags: word-order, adverb-placement

What determines the position of the adverb? Example: I could never learn to swim.  or  I never could learn to swim.

Comment: This is mostly a matter of style, with some nuance. For example, "never could" is potentially more emphatic. More emphatic still would be an alternative you haven't mentioned: "I could learn to swim never."

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to say.  There is a difference in nuance between these sentences. Since "could" has various interpretations, the difference is whether you are talking about future or past inability.  However I think these kind of differences vary based on the adverb and the context.

Comment: Also I don't think "could" is an *adverb*.  I think it's classed as a [*modal auxiliary* verb](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/auxiliary.htm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking, they mean something different. One is a statement about future events, and the other is about past events.

> I could never learn to swim.

Looking forward, learning to swim is not something I will ever be able to do.

> I never could learn to swim.

In the past, learning to swim was not something I was able to accomplish.

However, depending on context, people often use the first phrase when they mean the second.

But the actual answer to your question is to determine what you mean to say and then use the appropriate phrase.

Still, if the two phrases seem ambiguous they can be rephrased—based on a particular meaning. (The best way to avoid ambiguity is to remove **could** altogether.)

> I'll never learn to swim.
>   Nobody will ever be able to teach me to swim.
>   Swimming is impossible for me.
>   Swimming is not something I'll ever want to learn.
>
> I was never able to figure out how to swim.
>   Nobody was ever able to teach me how to swim.
>   Swimming was never possible for me.

Comment: "I never could learn to swim" *can* be cast as a future statement, but it can also be used for one in the past, another way of saying "I was never able to learn to swim" with something like "after all these years" or "after many attempts" implied. Try saying it to yourself with the stress on *could*: "I never *could* learn to swim."

Comment: @Robusto  But that's just what I said. "I never could learn to swim" is about the past.

Comment: *I never could learn to swim* referring to future impossibility? I don't think I've ever heard it used that way/

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I agree. I've never heard it used for the future either. Although I can *imagine* somebody mixing it up, I think it's quite unlikely—far less likely than mixing up the future tense with the past. (I assume you're replying to the first comment, the first part of which I didn't explicitly object to.)

Comment: Yes, responding to Robusto's comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think someone saying "I could never learn to swim" or "I never could learn to swim" can be both used in the past or future tense. For example, if you asked "have you ever tried to learn how to swim" - (past tense) - or "would you like to try to learn to swim" - (future tense) - could both be answered using both terms, but "I could never learn to swim" is probably more generally used in normal conversation, while "I never could learn to swim" would be used in specific dialogue.